# How to get $scope from inside a controller function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have the following problem: I have a function inside a controller, and the function decides the value of a $scope.name

```
app.controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    function myFunction() {
       $scope.name = 'myName';
    }
document.getElementById('my-id').addEventListener("click", myFunction);
}])
```

I cannot use ng-click for multiple reasons. **UPDATE:**
I cannot use ng-click due to [photoswipe](http://photoswipe.com/documentation/getting-started.html) gallery and [socialshare](https://github.com/720kb/angular-socialshare). I want to add custom FB share, and if I use ng-click it will close the photoswipe opened image. **Please see the example [here](http://aislynart.com/#/albums/Animals). Open an image and click on the top-left custom share button**

Note, even if I use the example here, it will not bind my $scope.name to the html.

If I try to log the value it works as a charm, eg.

```
console.log($scope.name); //will work perfectly
```

In the html it will not bind the value:

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
<button id="my-id">
   <p>{{name}}</p>
</button>
</div>
```

Comment: You should never directly interact with the DOM from controllers (i.e. no `document.getElement...`). This question is answerable per se (digest cycle is being bypassed), but to get a real Angular answer you need to change your approach. For that we'd need to know what problem you have with `ng-click`.

Comment: To update the scope out of angulars domain (native click handler, jQuery callback) use `$scope.$apply` but as @deceze said your doing it wrong this way.

Comment: I'd suggest you to open a new question with details about the issue between `ng-click` and photoswipe; it's too vague what exactly the issue is, but I'm pretty sure there's no reason it can't be solved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a topical solution, the problem is that a plain event listener will bypass the digest cycle. That means your `$scope` is getting updated, but Angular doesn't know about it, because the event which triggered the update is not on Angular's radar, and hence Angular doesn't update the template. The (***bad***) solution to this problem is to use [`$scope.$apply`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) to forcefully trigger a digest.

But again, **this is an un-Angular solution and you'd be off a lot better if you fixed whatever problem you have with `ng-click` instead.**